# MVC I need to somehow update main table and add record to foregin key relate table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    mediaguid = System.Guid.NewGuid();                      
                    qcreport.ReportsMedias.Add(new ReportsMedia()
                    {
                        reportId = qcreport.reportId,
                        actualFileName = file.FileName,
                        DateIssued = DateTime.Now,
                        contentType = file.ContentType,
                        mediaGuid = mediaguid
                    });


                }
            }

            //save whatever data to QC report                
            db.Entry(qcreport).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;                

            db.SaveChanges();
```

ReportsMedia is my ICollection: I added new one here and trying update existing qcreport Entity object

Comment: found the solution: need to replace to db.ReportsMedias.Add from qcreport.ReportsMedias.Add

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a specific object in your DB, then use this: `db.Entry(yourOldEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(yourNewEntry); db.SaveChanges();`

Obviously you first have to find `yourOldEntry` with a `db....Find(...)` or whatever, then modify it and then update it.